# DB connect class: bind issue

Tags: php, class, pdo, bind

I have a DB connect class, everything is fine, except the step while binding values, it inserts the last field data in all fields plus the type while binding returns the number 2 and not (INT, BOOL, NULL,...) as I specified:

[image]

So, it should insert:

pour fied1 in field1
pour fied2 in field2
pour fied3 in field3

and so on, here is the code:

```
<?php

final class crud {


public function __construct($connexionName) {

    $this->connexionName  = $connexionName;
}


public final function insert($tableName, $fields=array()){

        $this->tableName = $tableName;
        $this->fields    = $fields;


        foreach ($this->fields as $vf) {

            $inKeys[]       = $vf;
            $inKeysDotted[] = ':' . $vf;

            $insImKeys       = implode(', ', $inKeys);
            $insImKeysDotted = implode(', ', $inKeysDotted);


            $this->insImKeys         = $insImKeys;
            $this->insImKeysDotted   = $insImKeysDotted;

        }

            $this->insertedKeys         = $inKeys;
            $this->insertedKeysDotted   = $inKeysDotted;

            //print_r($this->insertedKeys);

            //echo '<br />';

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->tableName` ($this->insImKeys) VALUES ($this->insImKeysDotted);";
        //echo $sql.'<br />';

        $insertItems = $this->connexionName->prepare($sql);

        $this->insertItems    = $insertItems;

        //print_r($insertItems).'<br />';

} // end prepareStm()


public final function bindParams($setValues=array()){


    $combine = array_combine($this->insertedKeys, $setValues);

    foreach ($combine as $getKey => $getVal) {

        switch ($getVal) {
        case is_int($getVal):
            //echo $getVal .' is INT<br />';
            $setType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            //return PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case is_bool($getVal):
            //echo $getVal .' is BOOL<br />';
            $setType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            //return PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
        case is_null($getVal):
            //echo $getVal .' is NULL<br />';
            $setType = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            //return PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
        default:
            //echo $getVal .' is STR<br />';
            $setType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            //return PDO::PARAM_STR;
            break;

        return $setType;
    }


   echo "this->insertItems->bindParam($getKey, $getVal, $setType)<br />";
   $this->insertItems->bindParam($getKey, $getVal, $setType);

   //echo '<pre>';
   //print_r($this->insertItems);
   //echo '</pre>';


    }


} // end bindParams()


public final function executeQuery(){
    return $this->insertItems->execute();
}



}

require_once '../Included_Files/Connect.php';



$con = new crud($connexion);

echo '<br />';

$con->insert('test', array('field1', 'field2', 'field3'));
$con->bindParams(array('pour field1', 'pour field2', 'pour field3'));
$con->executeQuery();

?>
```

The result of echo and print_r are:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (:field1, :field2, :field3);
this->insertItems->bindParam(field1, pour field1, 2)

this->insertItems->bindParam(field2, pour field2, 2)

this->insertItems->bindParam(field3, pour field3, 2)
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in your code, one major and one minor.

First, because you are using [PDOStatement::bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), you are binding a *variable*, not a value. This means that when you call

```
$this->insertItems->bindParam("field1", $getVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$this->insertItems->bindParam("field2", $getVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$this->insertItems->bindParam("field3", $getVal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

over the three successive iterations of the loop, *all three* of those those fields are bound to the variable `$getVal`, whose value changes each time through the loop.

What you want to do instead is call [PDOStatement::bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). That will bind the *value of `$getVal`* (at the time you make the call) to the parameter, and not the variable itself.

This is your main problem, and resolving that will make your code (mostly) work.

Your smaller problem is your switch statement:

> ```
> switch ($getVal) {
>    case is_int($getVal):
>    ...
> ```

This is equivalent to writing `if($getVal == is_int($getVal))`. This means that if, say, `$getVal === '0'` (that is, `$getVal` is a string whose value evaluates to false in a boolean context), then `'0' == is_int($getVal)` ('0' is not an int, so is_int returns false), and you wind up trying to bind the string '0' as an integer.

Instead, you should replace the switch statement with a series if/else if statements, or instead use `switch(true)`.

Comment: I used if/else, still remain the same result: `if(is_int($getVal)){ $setType = PDO::PARAM_INT; }`

Comment: But did you change `bindParam()` to `bindValue()`? That is the major problem in your code that's preventing it from working at all.

Comment: well, if I quotted the params:  $setType = "PDO::PARAM_STR"; and echo them, it returns the corect values, I think since, it is not a string, it is just a parameter, it will return the number equivalent to that parameter, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: PDO::PARAM_STR should not have quotes around it. You didn't need to make that change, and it's unclear why you did.

Comment: I did just to test that I get the right param type, I think the bind issue is resolved, it is getting the number equivalent to that type